# What is meaning of the "time to head XXX" forms?

Tags: meaning

What is meaning of the "time to head XXX" forms?

Whole English context:http://mangahasu.se/onii-chan-wa-oshimai/vol-5-chapter-14-mahiro-and-a-little-adventure-c551795.html

[image: The English version]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking about the low quality English text in a cartoon that almost certainly wasn't even written by a native Anglophone.

Comment: I'm not sure the translator's first language,so what is correct where to post this question?please.@FumbleFingers

Comment: I just followed your link to the source. It looks as if the "translator" is someone called Nasdrovie, but I couldn't easily identify the name of whoever posted the "Anglicized" version of what appears to be originally a Japanese cartoon. Whoever he/she is, it looks to me as if you'd probably get an answer *on that very page* if you posted a question there (the poster has gone to some trouble to explain *clear file, kiribi,* etc.). But I advise you *not* to use it as a way of improving your English - it's really just "pseudo-English" as used by Japanese who know a few English words / phrases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase isn't **time to head**. It's **time to**, which a colloquial shortening of **it is time to**. In the comic, the character is thinking:

> [It is] time to head back.

The term **head back** means the same thing as **go back**. Her thought is interrupted in the middle of the word *back* when she sees the game center, so the author writes "ba-" to indicate the interruption.